# can not bind data in dynamically appends elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a row where i have a dropdownlist i can add row dynamically on page and binding an event to the selectbox.

The problem I have is that  select boxes I add via Ajax or DOM after the initial loop won't have the event bound.

here is my view part.

```
<div class="row" id="dsp">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select name="p_name[]" class="form-control p_name">
            <option value="">-Select Product-</option>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            <option value="{{$product->product_id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="p_code[]" id="p_code" class="form-control p_code" >
    </div>
```

here is my jquery part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dsp').on('change','.p_name',function(){
    var pid=$(this).val();
    //alert(pid);
    $.ajax({
      url:"{{route('getinfo')}}",
      method:'post',
      data:{id:pid,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
      success:function(response) {   

        //alert(response.code);
        $('.p_code').val(response.code);

      }
    });

  });
});
```

here is image.
[image: sample picture]

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Seriously what's up with people not linting their code when posting. If you are not going to bother with making your question clear, why should we bother to help you? All we ask is you organise your code so that we don't spend an extra 5min doing that work for you.

Comment: What is your question. Means Your change event is not working or else?

Comment: yes, event binding problem with dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM relationship to target the desired element the set its value. Here `.closest()` can be used to target common ancestor element then use `.find()` to target the desired `.p_code` and `unit_pctn` elemen

```
$('#dsp').on('change', '.p_name', function () {

    var pid = $(this).val();

    //Target common parent
    var parent = $(this).closest('.row');

    //alert(pid);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('getinfo')}}",
        success: function (response) {
            parent.find('.p_code').val(response.code);
            parent.find('.unit_pctn').val(response.pcs_per_ctn);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('getprice')}}",
        success: function (response) {
            parent.find('.u_price').val(response.client_price);
        }
    });

});
```

Note:  I think you should select the selector to bind event handler wisely. It seems you are using duplicate identifiers which will render your HTML invalid.